# Drag and Drop JLabel in top of another JLabel

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jpanel, jlabel

I have JPanel with two images as JLabels. I'm trying drag right side image and drop it on top of left side image and it should stay there after mouse released. Currently i'm able to drag the image but it goes under the drop location image. Second problem is when I press mouse on image, that location is different from actual image boundaries. How can I get the exact location relative to main panel?

Here is my coding.

```
public class loadLayout extends JPanel{

        @Override
        public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
            return false;
        }

        public loadLayout(){

            setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
            setMaximumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(600, 400));


            try {

                BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));
                JPanel leftP = new JPanel(null);
                JLabel leftL = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
                leftL.setSize(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
                leftL.setLocation(10, 10);
                leftP.add(leftL);

                JPanel rightP = new JPanel();
                BufferedImage img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("dragger.png"));
                JLabel rightL = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img2));
                rightL.setSize(img2.getWidth(), img2.getHeight());

                rightP.add(rightL);

                add(leftP);
                add(rightP);

                MouseAdapter mouseHandler = new MouseAdapter() {
                    private Point delta;

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

                        imagePoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(rightL, rightL.getX(), rightL.getY(), loadLayout.this);
                        Point origin = e.getPoint();

                        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(imagePoint, new Dimension(rightL.getWidth(), rightL.getHeight()));
                        if (bounds.contains(origin)) {
                            delta = new Point(origin.x - imagePoint.x, origin.y - imagePoint.y);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                        if (delta != null) {
                            imagePoint = e.getPoint();
                            imagePoint.translate(-delta.x, -delta.y);
                            rightL.setLocation(imagePoint);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

                        if(delta != null){
                            rightL.setLocation(delta);
                            revalidate();
                            repaint();
                        }

                        delta = null;                        
                    }
                };

                addMouseListener(mouseHandler);
                addMouseMotionListener(mouseHandler);


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DragnDropTest1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

[Location to press to drag the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8STTp.png)

[How it should be after..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz4Pd.png)

Comment: My question is when I clicked on the image it takes different location than the actual one. I want to get exact location.

Comment: Great stuff! That now makes my comments noise (deleted) and the close vote irrelevant (retracted). All the best with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have JPanel with two images as JLabels

Looks to me like you have a panel that contains 2 panels. Each of those panels contains a label. Why do you add each label to a second panel?

Get rid of the "wrapper" panels and just add the labels directly to the main panel.

> I'm trying drag right side image and drop it on top of left side image and it should stay there after mouse released

Swing paints components based on `Z Order`. As a component is added to the panel the ZOrder is increased and the component with the highest ZOrder is painted first, so basically the last component added to the panel is painted first.

So in your case the right label is painted before the left label.

If you want to drag the right label so it is painted AFTER the left label, then in your mousePressed code you can change the ZOrder of the component by using

```
JPanel parent = e.getComponent().getParent;
parent.setComponentZOrder(e.getComponent(), 0);
```

Now the component will be painted last as you drag it over the panel.